# Celery workers not working with redis

Tags: redis, celery

I tried to start the celery which consumes a data from REDIS . It is showing that celery has started (but not sure.. ) but this service could not spawn the workers pools.

Below message showing the status as **ACTIVE** :-

> celeryd.service - LSB: celery task worker daemon  Loaded: loaded
>   (/etc/init.d/celeryd; *bad*; vendor preset: enabled)    Active: active
>   (exited) since Wed 2017-09-20 13:40:12 UTC; 7min ago
>        Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

But still workers not created. I checked with running processes . Previously it was working fine with the current configuration . That means configuration is correct but when I restarted the application , this issue started to occur.

Second question is what is bad in below highlighted line :-

```
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/celeryd; ***bad***; vendor preset: enabled)
```

Please reply with your suggestions/answers . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh.. I figured it out .

Comment: In my case it was because of less memory . You can increase a RAM in case you are using unix/linux . But the reason could be different in different scenario's